# Install hangs with gray rectangle accross screen

Tags: install

I'm installing on a 2010 Mac Mini, off of USB.  Ubuntu 20.04 installs fine.  I disabled "splash" and "quiet" in grub.  I don't see any error messages.  The kernel boots and then hangs with a gray rectangle across a black screen.  It takes up about 1/3 of the screen down the middle.

I've tried adding "vga=ask" "vga=1280×720" and "GRUB_GFXMODE=1280×720."  None of those worked.  I still get the hanging grey bar.  My monitor is 4K.

Does anyone have some help with this one?

Thanks,

Kent

Answer (score 0):

Using nomodeset at boot worked.

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do